# Nginx location setting

Tags: nginx

nginx.conf

```
...
location ~ ^/file/ {
    root /ProjectData/b2b;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;  
}
```

file organization

```
ProjectData
  b2b
    img
      a.png
```

url: http://localhost:8008/file/img/a.png

How to set nginx.conf to make my url work without change my file organization?

Comment: Use alias instead of root

Comment: Worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `root` to `alias` and it worked.

```
location /file {
    alias /ProjectData/b2b;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;  
}
```